# Getting post object and slug to properly update in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using React with the Wordpress REST API.  The issue I am having is I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to (properly) use the component lifecycles to update the `Post` component when the slug property changes on the root `App` Component and fetching async data.

The way I have it set up currently, the `App` component state looks something like this:

```
this.state = {
   pages: this.getPages(),
   slug: this.getSlug(),
   homePage: this.fetchPost('home'),
};
```

So the `pages` property is a promise and the App component initially renders a Spinner component.  Eventually the async call receives a response.  I perform a filter on the array of post objects to look for the current page post.

```
const thePage = this.state.pages.filter(page => {
                return page.slug === slug;
            });
```

The filter returns an array with one object (this current page). I update the state with `this.setState({post: thePage[0]});`

When I change change routes with `react-router-dom`, the `slug` and `post` are not updating.  Below is my code.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App/App';

// Take the React component and show it on the screen
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

App JS:

```
// App.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import './App.scss';
import {wpAPI} from '../..//api';
import {/*loadState,*/ saveState} from '../loadState/loadState';
import FrontPage from '../../pages/FrontPage';
import Header from '../Header/Header';
import Post from '../Post/Post';
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar/Sidebar';
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer';
import Spinner from '../Spinner/Spinner';

// Create a React Component
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Bindings
        this.getPages = this.getPages.bind(this);
        this.getPages();

        this.state = {
            isHome: false,
            slug: this.props.location.pathname,
            fetchingPages: true,
            fetchingPost: true,
        };

        console.log('App State: (constructor)');
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch Data
     * @return {Promise}
     */
    getPages = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(wpAPI['pages']);

        this.setState({
            fetchingPages: false,
            pages: response.data
        });
        saveState(this.state);
    }

    getPage = (slug) => {
        const thePage = this.state.pages.filter(page => {
            return page.slug === slug.replace('/', '');
        });

        this.setState({
            isHome: false,
            fetchingPost: false,
            post: thePage[0],
            slug: slug,
        });
    }

    /**
     * The component has mounted.  Fetch post based on slug
     */
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('App State: (componentDidMount)');
        console.log(this.state);

        console.log('App Props: (componentDidMount)');
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        console.log('App State: (componentDidUpdate)');
        console.log(this.state);

        const {fetchingPages, fetchingPost, isHome} = this.state;
        const slug = this.props.location.pathname;

        if (this.state.slug !== this.props.location.pathname) {
            console.log('Slugs Dont match, getting page');
            this.getPage(slug);
        }

        if (slug === '/' && !isHome) {
            console.log('Setting isHome True');
            this.setState({
                isHome: true,
                fetchingPost: false
            });
        }

        if (fetchingPages === false && fetchingPost === true) {
            console.log('Fetching Post');

            this.getPage(slug);
        }
    }

    renderContent() {
        const {post, fetchingPost} = this.state;

        if (!fetchingPost) {
            return (
                <section id="app" className="animated fadeIn">
                    <Header />
                    <main>
                        <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <FrontPage {...props} /> } />
                        <Route path="/:slug" exact render={(props) => <Post post={post} /> } />
                    </main>
                    <Sidebar />
                    <Footer />
                </section>
            )
        }

        return <Spinner message='loading data...' />;
    }

    render() {
        return this.renderContent();
    }
};

export default withRouter(App);
```

Post.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import './Post.scss';
import Spinner from '../Spinner/Spinner';

class Post extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            slug: props.slug,
            post: props.post,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Post State: (componentDidUpdate)');
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log('Post State: (componentDidUpdate)');
    }

    render() {
        if ( this.state.post ) {
            const {post} = this.state;

            return (
                <div className={`post post-${post.id} ${post.slug} animated fadeIn`}>
                    <header>
                        <h1 className="small-caps" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.title.rendered}}></h1>
                    </header>
                    <section id="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.content.rendered}}></section>
                </div>
            )
        }

        return <Spinner message='Fetching Post...'/>
    }
}

export default withRouter(Post);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in your code to say that when your App receives new props from the `withRouter` HOC, then update `state.slug`.

You could add:

```
this.setState({
    slug: this.getSlug();
});
```

to your `componentDidUpdate()` function, however I'm not sure why you need it as state when it's available as a prop anyway in `this.props.location.pathname` which is being passed down to your FrontPage component, and could just as easily be passed down to your Posts component in the same way.

Comment: I was setting it in state because I was using the state.slug to compare with the router prop value as a means to check when to update the post - it's also shorter to type this.getSlug() than the path in the prop :) . I guess the main question I have now is how to get the post component to properly update when state.pages is loaded.  I plan to make this offline capable.  It already has function I took out that saved the requests to localStorage and loads them if set, but removed them for trouble shooting and simplicity sake of this question.  I'd be set if Post updated correctly.